# What is the English name for the "sign" that is put between words to add another word?

Tags: word-request

There is a sign like "roof" or two "two hands asking something" which used in handwriting and in case that someone forgot to write a word, then he put this sign and above it the missed word or the adding. 
What is called in English?

I attached an example. The sign here is in red color.

[image]

Comment: This is *an* example! you need one more *caret!*

Comment: Thank you. I thought it, but it was late already... The important thing is that I succeeded to pass the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although what you're showing in your example is understandable, what you are probably looking for is called a

> [**caret**](http://www.csuchico.edu/pub/writing-style-guide/copy-editing.shtml)

and marks an insertion point for letters or words.

Strictly speaking, in the proofreading / copy editing world, the caret appears below the typed line and **points upwards**, and the handwritten edited text appears above the typed line

[image: here]